# NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) being executed last

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, healthkit

I'm having a problem with `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)`. I want to authenticate my app against some API and if the authentication is successful then the app will let the user to authorise health kit and finally fetch some data from there.

I have this in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
print ("AUTHORIZING APIGEE!!!")
authorizeApigee()
if (self.errorApigee == 0) {
    print ("APIGEE AUTHORIZED!")
    // We cannot access the user's HealthKit data without specific permission.
    print ("AUTHORIZING HEALTHKIT!!")
    getHealthKitPermission()
    print ("HEALTHKIT AUTORIZED!")
} else {
    print ("APIGEE UNAUTHORIZED!")
}
```

and this is the authorising function:

```
// Authenticating app with Apigee Health APIx
func authorizeApigee(){
        // Send HTTP GET Request


        let scriptUrl = "https://fhirsandbox-prod.apigee.net/oauth/v2"
        let urlWithParams = scriptUrl + "/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials"
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlWithParams);

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // Add Basic Authorization

        let username = "****"
        let password = "****"
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
        request.setValue(base64LoginString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            // Check for error
            if error != nil
            {
                self.errorApigee = 1
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // Print out response string
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

The problem is that even though `authorizeApigee()` is called, the app stops at `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)`, goes out of the function, obviously `errorApigee` variable is not updated and therefore it goes to the next step of authorising health kit without authorising Apigee. Finally when health kit was authorised it goes back and authorises Apigee.

Any idea why this might happen at all?
Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `authorizeApigee()` is async. So `getHealthKitPermission()` will be called before it gets the request values...

Comment: Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple example how to use `completion`  :

```
func authorizeApigee(completion: (auth: Bool) -> Void) {
           // Send HTTP GET Request
    let scriptUrl = "https://fhirsandbox-prod.apigee.net/oauth/v2"
    let urlWithParams = scriptUrl + "/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials"
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlWithParams);

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // Add Basic Authorization

    let username = "****"
    let password = "****"
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
    request.setValue(base64LoginString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        // Check for error
        if error != nil
        {
            self.errorApigee = 1
            print("error=\(error)")
             completion(auth: false)
        }

        // Print out response string
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
         completion(auth: true)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And how to use :

```
 self.authorizeApigee { (auth) -> Void in
        if (auth) {
           getHealthKitPermission()
        } else {
          //print errors
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to make this shorter, you can just do `auth in` instead of `(auth) -> Void in`, and you can also remove the brackets in the `if (auth)` statement

Answer (score 1):

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest() is executed in another thread. It's so that the main application thread doesn't hang and wait for the request to complete. If you want a code block to run after the async task is complete, I suggest you use a completion block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use closure because api calling work in `async` manner so first change your function definition like this

```
func authorizeApigee(completion: (Int) -> ()){
    let scriptUrl = "https://fhirsandbox-prod.apigee.net/oauth/v2"
    let urlWithParams = scriptUrl + "/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials"
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlWithParams);

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // Add Basic Authorization

    let username = "****"
    let password = "****"
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
    request.setValue(base64LoginString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        // Check for error
        if error != nil
        {
            completion(0)
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        // Print out response string
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        completion(1)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Now call your function like this

```
self.authorizeApigee() { (result) -> () in
     if result == 0 {
          print ("APIGEE AUTHORIZED!")
          // We cannot access the user's HealthKit data without specific permission.
          print ("AUTHORIZING HEALTHKIT!!")
          getHealthKitPermission()
          print ("HEALTHKIT AUTORIZED!")
      } else {
          print ("APIGEE UNAUTHORIZED!")
      }  
}
```